# WP-Debug Issue with Image Resizing Script (WordPress)

Tags: image, wordpress, image-resizing

Working with Victor Teixeira's image resizing script, and have used it on several premium themes.  It functions great, but I'm getting some notices when I run the debugger, and I don't know how to resolve it.  I wonder if anyone can help?  :)

Here are the notices:

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: file_path in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/51370/domains/minimalpixels.com/html/wp-content/themes/paragon/framework/functions/basicFunctions.php on line 129

    Notice: Undefined index: extension in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/51370/domains/minimalpixels.com/html/wp-content/themes/paragon/framework/functions/basicFunctions.php on line 130

    Notice: Undefined index: dirname in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/51370/domains/minimalpixels.com/html/wp-content/themes/paragon/framework/functions/basicFunctions.php on line 133

    Notice: Undefined variable: image_src in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/51370/domains/minimalpixels.com/html/wp-content/themes/paragon/framework/functions/basicFunctions.php on line 139

    Notice: Undefined variable: image_src in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/51370/domains/minimalpixels.com/html/wp-content/themes/paragon/framework/functions/basicFunctions.php on line 139

    Notice: Undefined variable: image_src in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/51370/domains/minimalpixels.com/html/wp-content/themes/paragon/framework/functions/basicFunctions.php on line 194

    Notice: Undefined variable: image_src in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/51370/domains/minimalpixels.com/html/wp-content/themes/paragon/framework/functions/basicFunctions.php on line 195

    Notice: Undefined variable: image_src in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/51370/domains/minimalpixels.com/html/wp-content/themes/paragon/framework/functions/basicFunctions.php on line 196
```

And here is the code:

```
 function vt_resize( $attach_id = null, $img_url = null, $width, $height, $crop = false ) {

// this is an attachment, so we have the ID
if ( $attach_id ) {

    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach_id, 'full' );
    $file_path = get_attached_file( $attach_id );

// this is not an attachment, let's use the image url
} else if ( $img_url ) {

    $file_path = parse_url( $img_url );
    $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file_path['path'];

    //$file_path = ltrim( $file_path['path'], '/' );
    //$file_path = rtrim( ABSPATH, '/' ).$file_path['path'];

    $orig_size = getimagesize( $file_path );

    $image_src[0] = $img_url;
    $image_src[1] = $orig_size[0];
    $image_src[2] = $orig_size[1];
}

[129] $file_info = pathinfo( $file_path );
[130] $extension = '.'. $file_info['extension'];

// the image path without the extension
[133]$no_ext_path = $file_info['dirname'].'/'.$file_info['filename'];

$cropped_img_path = $no_ext_path.'-'.$width.'x'.$height.$extension;

// checking if the file size is larger than the target size
// if it is smaller or the same size, stop right here and return
[139]if ( $image_src[1] > $width || $image_src[2] > $height ) {

    // the file is larger, check if the resized version already exists (for $crop = true but will also work for $crop = false if the sizes match)
    if ( file_exists( $cropped_img_path ) ) {

        $cropped_img_url = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $cropped_img_path ), $image_src[0] );

        $vt_image = array (
            'url' => $cropped_img_url,
            'width' => $width,
            'height' => $height
        );

        return $vt_image;
    }

    // $crop = false
    if ( $crop == false ) {

        // calculate the size proportionaly
        $proportional_size = wp_constrain_dimensions( $image_src[1], $image_src[2], $width, $height );
        $resized_img_path = $no_ext_path.'-'.$proportional_size[0].'x'.$proportional_size[1].$extension;            

        // checking if the file already exists
        if ( file_exists( $resized_img_path ) ) {

            $resized_img_url = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $resized_img_path ), $image_src[0] );

            $vt_image = array (
                'url' => $resized_img_url,
                'width' => $proportional_size[0],
                'height' => $proportional_size[1]
            );

            return $vt_image;
        }
    }

    // no cache files - let's finally resize it
    $new_img_path = image_resize( $file_path, $width, $height, $crop );
    $new_img_size = getimagesize( $new_img_path );
    $new_img = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $new_img_path ), $image_src[0] );

    // resized output
    $vt_image = array (
    [194]'url' => $new_img,
    [195]'width' => $new_img_size[0],
    [196]'height' => $new_img_size[1]
    );

    return $vt_image;
}

// default output - without resizing
$vt_image = array (
    'url' => $image_src[0],
    'width' => $image_src[1],
    'height' => $image_src[2]
);

return $vt_image;
 }
```

Thanks you in advance.  This issue is causing me a headache :)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you had posted the entire file or otherwise annotate the line numbers.

Comment: Hi AJweb,  I added some line numbers in brackets.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the line numbers is a bit tricky to know where exactly the errors are being encountered, but here is my guess. The first error, and probably the one that triggers the rest is:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: file_path in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/51370/domains/minimalpixels.com/html/wp-content/themes/paragon/framework/functions/basicFunctions.php on line 129
```

And it is probably triggered in this line:

```
$file_info = pathinfo( $file_path );
```

The function doesn't seem to me to be very well designed. The first two arguments, `$attach_id` and `$image_url` are optional (both could be omitted), judging from their default NULL values and the checks in the code. But the code is defining the `$file_path` var by checking the presence of either `$attach_id` or `$image_url` (`if` and `elseif`). So, if none of these is present `$file_path` will not be defined, and hence the error notice.

If the function can't do its job without one of these parameters (`$image_url` or `$attach_id`), it should return after the elseif:

```
if($attach_id) { /* code */ }
elseif($image_url) { /* code */ }
else return False;
```